# Jquery can't show data on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

so i got some problem while i want to show data,
how do i show data from database on modal ajax jquery? i have tried tutor but it's still same.

this is my laravel blade html :

```
            <div class="modal fade" id="ajax-modal" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="userShowModal"></h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                         
                             <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nama</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama" name="nama" value="" required="" disabled>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
               
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="kategori" name="kategori" placeholder="Enter Email" value="" disabled>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </form>
                     
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

and this is my jquery code using ajax :

```
  $('body').on('click', '.detail-narasumber', function () {
            var data_id = $(this).data('id');
            $.get('narasumber/'+data_id, function(data) {
                dataType: 'json',
                
                $('#userShowModal').html("User Details");
                $('#ajax-modal').modal('show');
                
                $('#id').val(data.id);
                $('#nama').val(data.nama);
                $('#kategori').val(data.kategori);
                $('#nomorhp').val(data.nomorhp);
                $('#email').val(data.email);
                $('#jk').val(data.jk);
                $('#pendidikan').val(data.pendidikan);
                $('#pekerjaan').val(data.pekerjaan);
                $('#kota').val(data.kota);
                $('#provinsi').val(data.provinsi);
            });
        });
```

Comment: why have you disabled your input text fields?

Comment: to differentiate between my show modal and edit modal

Comment: use readonly instead of disable in your show modal and than you can store value in those input fields

Comment: ok maybe i'll do it later but the main problem is idk why my modal didn't show value from my ajax jquery

Comment: have you checked the values of variables data.id,data.nama..etc using console.log ..does they are storing any value

Comment: yes , they storing value. when i check on inspect network, it's fetch all value that i need but i can't show it on modal

Comment: sorry bro i couldn't be able to help you but i can say there's something wrong with ajax itself

Comment: thank you bro, already solved. i just write my selector that's is double written with selector to get edit value

Comment: thats good to hear bro...keep on coding